# How compare date parts in SUMIFS formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I want compare a date part with a string and sum the values when the date part match with the string.

`$A2` is a `YEAR STRING`. Ex: `2019`

`'Other Sheet'!$U2:$U` is a column with the values to sum when the condition returns true.

`'Other Sheet'!$E2:$E` is a column with the date of the records.

```
-- THE FORMULA ABOVE RETURNS 0 (obviously)
=SUMIFS('Other Sheet'!$U2:$U;'Other Sheet'!$E2:$E;$A2)

-- I NEED SOME WAY TO DO SOMETHING LIKE
=SUMIFS('Other Sheet'!$U2:$U;YEAR('Other Sheet'!$E2:$E);$A2)
```

Is it possible solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(
    'Other Sheet'!$U2:$U;
    QUERY('Other Sheet'!$E2:$E;"SELECT YEAR(E) LABEL YEAR(E) ''");
    $A2
)
```